# Standard library containers producing a lot of copies on rvalues in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw, rvalue-reference

I'm writing a app for both linux & windows, and noticed that the GCC build is producing a lot of useless calls to the copy constructor.

Here's an example code to produce this behavior:

```
struct A
{
    A()                { std::cout << "default" << std::endl; }
    A(A&& rvalue)      { std::cout << "move"    << std::endl; }
    A(const A& lvalue) { std::cout << "copy"    << std::endl; }
    A& operator =(A a) { std::cout << "assign"  << std::endl; return *this; }
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_copy_semantics)
{
    std::vector<A> vec_a( 3 );
}
```

This test just creates a vector of 3 elements. I expect 3 default constructor calls and 0 copies as there are no `A` lvalues.

In Visual C++ 2010, the output is:

```
default
move
default
move
default
move
```

In GCC 4.4.0 (MinGW), (-O2 -std=c++0x), the output is:

```
default
copy
copy
copy
```

What is going on and how do I fix it? Copies are expensive for the actual class, default construction and moves are cheap.

Comment: Have you looked at the `<vector>` header? What is the constructor doing? The GCC behavior is consistent with the C++03 spec, where an object is default constructed then copied N times. It's possible that your version of the standard library doesn't support the new constructor added to C++0x, which default constructs N elements.

Comment: Because the example uses C++0x language features, I'm assuming this is a question about the C++0x spec, not the C++03 spec.

Comment: Same output with GCC 4.5

Comment: What options (flags) did you use to compile the g++ version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both implementations (Visual C++ 2010 and GCC 4.4.0) are in error.  The correct output is:

```
default
default
default
```

This is specified in 23.3.5.1 [vector.cons]/4:

Requires: T shall be DefaultConstructible.

The implementation is not allowed to assume that A is either MoveConstructible nor CopyConstructible.

Comment: You're right, my next question was going to be why is VC move constructing at all. Is there anything that can be done? Any idea if stlport or ea's implementations are more conforming?

Comment: This std::lib: http://libcxx.llvm.org/ gets the right answer, but hasn't been ported to Windows.  There are parties interested in porting it to Windows and who could no doubt use help.

Comment: I've reported the Visual C++ issue.

Comment: @James if it's actually a std library issue not a compiler issue you should probably report it to [Dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com/) too

Comment: Just to follow up:  this has been fixed in Visual C++.  If you compile the code with the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview, it will produce the correct output.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the problem is that the version of g++ that you have does not have a C++0x fully compliant library. In particular, in C++03, the size constructor of std::vector has the following signature:

```
// C++ 03
explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T(),
const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

With that function signature and your call, a temporary is created, then bound by the constant reference and copies of it are created for each one of the elements.

while in C++0x there are different constructors:

```
// C++0x
explicit vector(size_type n);
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

In this case, your call will match the first signature, and the elements should be default constructed with placement new over the container (as @Howard Hinnant correctly points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865515/standard-library-containers-producing-a-lot-of-copies-on-rvalues-in-gcc/4865741#4865741) the compiler should not call the move constructor at all).

You can try and check if more recent versions of g++ have an updated standard library, or you can work around the issue by manually adding the elements:

```
std::vector<A> v;
v.reserve( 3 );     // avoid multiple relocations
while (v.size() < 3 ) v.push_back( A() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this then:

```
std::vector<A> vec_a;
vec_a.reserve(3);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  vec_a.push_back(A());
```

What you're trying to do is force the initialization process to use construct+move for each value instead of construct and then copy/copy/copy.  These are just different philosophies; the libraries authors couldn't possibly know which is going to be the best for any given type.

Comment: This is more than different philosophies.  The C++0x draft specifies the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can add special (cheap) case to copy ctor algorithm when copying default constructed object to "this" object. It's just a workaround, however, the behaviour is strange enough.
Both compilers (libraries) create a temporary object on the stack, then gcc copies this temporary to the targets 3 times;  msvc recreates temporary object 3 times (!) (on the stack too) and moves 3 timesn to targets. I don't understand why they don't create objects directly in place.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that all 3 variants do not violate C++0x draft. It requires following:
1. Constructs a vector with n value-initialized elements
2. T shall be DefaultConstructible
3. Linear in n

All 3 variants satisfy 1, as default + copy, default + move are equivalent to default
All 3 variants satisfy 3
All 3 variants satisfy 2: they work for DefaultConstructible types. Specific algorithm can be used for Moveable types. It is a general practice in STL to use different versions of algorithms for types with different capabilities.